# React call functions on renderless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to have a component for handling settings, this component (called `Settings`) stores state using `useState()`, for example the primary color.

I need to create a single instance of this component and make it available to every component in the app. Luckily, I already pass down a state dict to every component (I'm very unsure if this is the correct way to achieve that btw), so I can just include this Settings constant.

My problem is that I don't know how to create the component for this purpose, so that I can call its functions and pass it to children.

Here is roughly what my Settings component looks like:

```
const Settings = (props) => {
    const [primaryColor, setPrimaryColor] = useState("")
    const getColorTheme = (): string => {
        return primaryColor
    }
    const setColorTheme = (color: string): void => {
        setPrimaryColor(color)
    }
    return null
}


export default Settings
```

Then I would like to be able to do something like this somewhere else in the app:

```
const App = () => {
    const settings = <Settings />
    return (
        <div style={{ color: settings.getColorTheme() }}></div>
    )
}
```

Bear in mind that I'm completely new to react, so my approach is probably completely wrong.

Comment: What you are looking for is context.

Comment: There are no renderless components, if you want to share state you can use the Context api from react. You should not use a component for this. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: No, `Settings` should be a ordinary class, not a component at all

Comment: @mousetail That was my original thought, however the components using the values from the settings class weren't updating when the values changed.

Comment: Also, you are using React hooks, but referring to your state like `this.state.primaryColor`. It should just be `primaryColor`. You aren't using class components.

Comment: @DanZuzevich I apologize, I originally had this as a class component and then switched and forgot to change that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom ***Higher Order Component(HOC)*** for this purpose, which is easier than creating a context(even thougn context is also a HOC). A HOC takes a component and returns a new component. You can send any data from your HOC to the received component.

```
const withSettings = (Component) => {
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState({})
  // ...
  // ...
  <Component {...props} settings={settings}/>
);
```

And you can use it like this:

```
const Component = ({ settings }) => {
   ...your settings UI
}
export default SettingsUI = withSettings(Component);
```

You can read more about HOCs in the [official react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: They want a shared state across the entire app, but this solution will cause each component to have its own independent state.